# Arduino UNO(9600) with Wizfi250 cannot send data to Ubidots

Tags: arduino-uno

I met a problem, that I used to success to send data to Ubidots using the code, but I cannot send it now, I tried to use another Ubidots account and it also does not work.Could someone help me with this, thank you very much.
PS. the code can make the device connected with WIFI, but cannot send the data to Ubidots.

```
#include "UbidotsWizFi250.h"

#define TOKEN "YNbIJdlwtH8s9p4xYNlZTuqhB6bfYY"  // Replace it with your Ubidots token
#define ID "5795e2f876254249c8ce246a" // Replace it with your Ubidots' variable ID

#define WLAN_SSID       "XXXXX"  // Your WiFi SSID, cannot be longer than 32 characters!
#define WLAN_PASS       "xxxxxxxxx"  // Replace it with your WiFi pass
// Security can be OPEN, WEP, WPA, WPAAES, WPA2AES, WPA2TKIP, WPA2
#define WLAN_SECURITY   "WPA2"

Ubidots client(TOKEN);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  while(!client.wifiConnection(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY));

}

void loop() {
  int value = analogRead(A4);
  client.add(ID,value);
  client.sendAll();
  Serial.println("--------------------");
  delay(1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrite the code of library of ubidots-wizfi250 in Arduino, and find out the problem I met.

WizFi250's interface mode(UART or SPI) are decided due to first input signal after doing factory default. so I may as well do factory default one's first.
For doing factory default,I pressed function button on WizFi250-EVE three times. This is description of Function Pin or Function button.
Only using SPI mode, I can send HTTP request! That is why we cannot send data to Ubidots sometimes.

Here is the error we got, [TCP Send Error], Solution: Change WizFI250 mode to SPI.

Comment: https://github.com/NaSao/MoistureAlarm/blob/master/pushUbidotsData.ino Here you can find my code